# Assigning result of getchar() to a struct member pointer

Tags: c, getchar

I've been trying to create a function that assigns `getchar()` to a pointer (`p_customers`) to a struct member (`last_name`), but I keep getting compiler errors or a segmentation fault. Here's what I have so far:

```
/* A customer account receivable record                               */
struct customer
{
   char  last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1]; /* Customer last name          */
   float amount;                       /* Amount the customer owes    */
   int   priority;                     /* Customer priority           */
};

void get_customers(struct customer *p_customers_start, 
                               int number_customers)
{
   struct customer *p_customers; /* Points to the account receivable  */
                                 /* customer                          */
   char            *p_last_name; /* Points to the last name character */

   /* Loop processing account receivable customer data                */
   for (p_customers=p_customers_start;
       (p_customers-p_customers_start) < number_customers;
        p_customers++)
   {
      /* Print out account receivable customer                        */
      printf(   "\nCustomer #%d:", 
               *p_customers - *p_customers_start + 1);

      /* Obtain last name of customer                                 */
      printf("   \nEnter the customer's last name: ");
      getchar();
      do
      {
          p_customers->last_name++ = getchar();
      }
      while(*p_last_name != NEW_LINE);
      p_last_name = END_OF_STRING;
   }
}
```

I have no clue what the problem is but could anyone clue me in on how to fix it?

Comment: Why the solo unassigned `getchar()`?  To read the assumed newline left over from prior input?  You need to check for EOF as well as newline, and the normal way to do that is with a `while` loop:  `int ch; int i = 0; while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') p_customers->last_name[i++] = ch;`  This works whether you have `char last_name[NAME_SIZE];` or `char *last_name;` in the structure — but it doesn't prevent buffer overflow.  There's no information in the question about what the sizes might be, but you should check that there is no buffer overflow.

Comment: Consider using fgets/scanf to read the whole customer name with one call. No point in reinventing those functions

Comment: I need to use getchar(), but I can't get the program to take the name without getting a segmentation fault. I just need to figure out how to configure the pieces to accept the name and put it where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the complete code?  Above code is too obscure to give any hint correct analysis.  However, I could make below comments based on assumptions:
  p_customers->last_name and p_last_name mayn't be referring to the same location.  As a result, "last_name++ = getchar()" keeps on reading the characters and tries to put in addresses beyond its limit.  This causes segfault.

Comment: There's the complete function, but my problem is assigning the pointer to the struct member, as well as holding the name.

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction is allowed on numeric types, but structures can't be subtracted from one another.  So when you say "*p_customers - *p_customers_start + 1" there is no meaning for "`*p_customers_start+1" and "*p_customers - <previous_expression>`".

For e.g., if a structure has employee records, what does subtraction of one from another mean?

I hope you wanted current customer number. If yes, you can use just "`p_customers - p_customers_start +1"`.

The name of array is a "constant pointer".  So it can never be changed.  When you say "`p_customers->last_name++`", you are trying to change a constant (pointer), which is not allowed.

Consider a situation where the user first gives NEWLINE for last name before giving actual last name. And in case that last name length is greater than MAX_NAME_LENGTH, you end up overwriting an area beyond the limits of array last_name.  When that happens you are getting the segmentation fault.